# Gráficos em JS , erro ao inserir dados da BD

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho em mãos um enorme problema. Eu tenho alguns gráficos em `js`, onde eu preciso que os dados inseridos neles venham da base dados.

Mas da forma como o código `js` está construido , eu não consigo encontrar nenhuma maneira de atribuir os dados da base de dados nos gráficos. No entanto já atribui os dados da base de dados a outras variáveis `js`, para facilitar.

Ainda assim estou com dificuldades .Espero que alguém consiga me ajudar :/

**ATENÇÃO:** Não é simplesmente substituir as variáveis uma a uma, e sim fazer de uma maneira que o processo seja automático, e sempre que se adicione ou mude um valor na base de dados, o gráfico mude automaticamente . Eu pensei em fazer um ciclo `while` ou `for` , mas não sei como!

Aqui está a forma como as variáveis estão atribuídas no `JS` dos dados vindos da `BD`:

```
var row=[];
<?php
$graph=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM lucro")or die("erro");
if($graph->num_rows>0){
    ?>
    var num=<?php echo $graph->num_rows;?>;
      for(var i=0;i<=<?php echo $graph->num_rows; ?>;i++){
        row[i]=[];
      }
    <?php
    $i=0;
    while($row=$graph->fetch_assoc() and $i<=$graph->num_rows){
      $data=date('M',strtotime($row['data']));
      ?>
        row[0][<?php echo $i+1; ?>]="<?php echo $data; ?>";
        row[<?php echo $i; ?>][0]=<?php echo $row['lucro'];?>;

      <?php
    $i++;
    }
}?>
var i=0;
```

E aqui temos o código do gráfico onde quero trocar por estas variáveis:

```
//GRAFICO do lucro p/ANO
 var myConfig = {
  type: "bar",
  plotarea: {
    adjustLayout: true
  },
  scaleX: {
    label: {
      text: "em MILHÕES"
    },

  //AQUI EM BAIXO É ONDE QUERO INSERIR AS VARIAVEIS JS COM OS DADOS DA BD:
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug"]
  },
  series: [{

  //AQUI EM BAIXO É ONDE QUERO INSERIR AS VARIAVEIS JS COM OS DADOS DA BD:
    values: [20, 40, 25, 50, 15, 45, 33, 34]
  }]
};

zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: "80%",
  width: "100%"
});
```

Comment: Queres que faça atualização da tabela só no refresh da pág ou sem ser preciso refresh?

Comment: é igual ! eu quero é arranjar maneira de consseguir inserir as variaveis JS que estão a receber os dados da base de dados, no gráfico , de maneira a que sempre que manipule os dados na base de dados, os dados do gráfico tambem alterem!

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim:

```
$labelsJS = array();
$valsJS = array();

while($row=$graph->fetch_assoc() and $i<=$graph->num_rows){
  $data=date('M',strtotime($row['data']));
  ?>
    row[0][<?php echo $i+1; ?>]="<?php echo $data; ?>";
    row[<?php echo $i; ?>][0]=<?php echo $row['lucro'];?>;

    $labelsJS[] = $data;
    $valsJS[] = $row['lucro'];
  <?php
   $i++;
}

$labelsJS = json_encode($labelsJS);
$valsJS = json_encode($valsJS);
```

Depois no js faça, suponho que aqui já ver a variável `$labelsJS` e `$datas` declaradas e com os valores inseridos acima:

```
var labels = <?= "JSON.parse('" .$labelsJS. "');"; ?>
var values = <?= "JSON.parse('" .$valsJS. "');"; ?>

//GRAFICO do lucro p/ANO
var myConfig = {
  type: "bar",
  plotarea: {
    adjustLayout: true
  },
  scaleX: {
    label: {
      text: "em MILHÕES"
    },
    labels: labels
  },
  series: [{
    values: values
  }]
};
```